Can I run a function after navigating to a new page and waiting for that page to finish loading?
I have a script that executes a function following a click event. This function sets cookies and redirects to a new URL. I would like to delay the execution of another function until the new URL has fully loaded. How can I achieve this?
At the moment the script basically looks like this:
function setAndNavigate(event){

    event.preventDefault()

    //code setting cookies

    //navigating to new url
    window.location.href = "http://newurl.com"
}

//click event listener runs the setAndNavigate function
var link = document.getElementById("launch");
link.addEventListener("click", setAndNavigate);

//using navigate event listener to kick off function once page url changes
navigation.addEventListener("navigate", (event) => {
        this.newFunction();
    });

//new function
function newFunction(){
    //new function code
}


I am using the navigate event listener to check for a navigation event and then running the code within that. However, at the moment, the new function runs before the new page has finished loading. I want the code to run on the new page once it has finished loading the UI.
This is a test environment and I don't have access to the application code.

I assume this is all on the same origin? If so, use an iFrame and trigger onload of that

on the new page check the cookies (or querystring or localStorage) and if condition is right then execute newFunction() which must be defined in the new page.

So basisclly you need to change
navigation.addEventListener("navigate", (event) => {
        this.newFunction();
    });

to "http://newurl.com" js script files
and use
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',(event) => {
        this.newFunction();
    })

DOMContentLoaded event will trigger if your content in "http://newurl.com" page is completely load dont't forget to move
newFunction();

to your new page script too.
